# What percentage of the network bandwidth "on the wire" is used for the message data?

Tags: bandwidth

A 1000 byte message is sent over the network using a protocol stack with HTTP, TCP, IP, and Ethernet. Each protocol header is 20 bytes long. What percentage of the network bandwidth "on the wire" is used for the message data? Give a numeric answer only.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Please how did you arrive at 42? Thank you.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/42_(number)

Comment: what is the answer ? i think its 94 percent

Answer (score 0):

total network bandwith on the wire -> 1000 byte message + 80 byte protocol headers = 1080 bytes.

So the percentage for the message is 93.